# How to remove inline css width: 100%; display: inline-block; from react-slick

Tags: react-slick

I am not sure why react-slick adds bellow inline properties while forming the slider.

```
width: 100%; display: inline-block;
```

Because of this my applications own CSS doesn't work and behaves differently. Please help me understanding and resolve this.

Please follow the mentioned link, where I tried to mimic the issue related to react-slick
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-b8wcgf

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to remove it. But you can fix it by adding one more div after Slider components

```
<Slider>
 <div>       //add div here
  <div className="product-wrap">

  </div>
 </div>     //close div
</Slider>
```

Answer (score -1):

You need in CSS add after the element value `!important`.
For example:

```
.product-wrap {
  position: relative;
  width: 30px !important; 
  display: grid !important;
  border: 1px solid red; 
}
```

Instead of 30px and grid type your values but keep `!important`.

Comment: This is not a good solution as we should never have to add !important to our css, the best solution is to find an alternative to react-slick as is too big for any application, but if you have to use it here: https://github.com/akiran/react-slick/issues/1378 is a good solution, wrap your div around a react fragment and it won't add the width and display properties.

react-slick alternatives: https://itnext.io/javascript-sliders-will-kill-your-website-performance-5e4925570e2b